# linux iterate over files in directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, iteration

I'm trying to iterate over each file in a directory.  Here's my code so far.

```
while read inputline
do
  input="$inputline"
  echo "you entered $input";

if [ -d "${input}" ]
  then
    echo "Good Job, it's a directory!"

    for d in $input
      do
        echo "This is $d in directory."
      done
   exit
```

my output is always just one line

```
this is $input directory.
```

why isn't this code working? what am I doing wrong?

Cool.  When I echo it prints out

```
$input/file
```

Why does it do that?  Shouldn't it just print out the file without the directory prefix?

Comment: `csh` derived shells have a significantly different syntax (`foreach`) than those derived from the Bourne shell (`for`), so it is helpful to tag the question with the one you mean...

Comment: what is your use case for this? if no, you might as well use find -type d.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for d in "$input"/*
```

Comment: why add double quote " around $input, is there a good reason doing this? I found out " for d in $input/* " also works. Thanks.

Comment: If $input has spaces etc. you need to quote.

Comment: @LionLai See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to simplify it somewhat and get rid of the directory check, you could just write it to work on files and directories, perhaps something like:

```
read inputline
ls "$inputline" | while read f; do
    echo Found "$f"
done
```

Comment: No, [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score -1):

You would think that looping over files would be easy, right? But this is full of pitfalls in bash.

Using globs is **the WORST**.  Trust me, don't do it

```
for x in *; do          # <--- bad for many reasons
    echo the file name is $x
done
```

Using find is better, for instance.

```
for x in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`; do  # <-- assume no filename has spaces
    echo the file name is $x
done
```

`find` has a lot of options to filter results by name, by date, by owner... whatever. It is very powerful.

However using a `for-find` FAILS if the filename contains spaces.  To fix that use...

```
while read x; do
    echo the file name is $x
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

Or if you don't like that weird `done` syntax, instead you can use:

```
result=`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f`
while read x; do
    echo the file name is $x
done <<< $result
```

However, what if the filename contains a linefeed?! Can that happen? Yes it can happen, but it is extremely rare.  So if you are *PARANOID* you can do:

```
while read -r -d '' x; do
    echo the file name is $x
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
```

In my opinion the extra mess is not worth it, so I don't recommend it. People who put linefeeds in filenames deserve to feel pain.

Comment: I think you need grounding when advising against globs. A very reputable shell script linter (31k stars on GitHub) says exactly the opposite, see [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2045). What's wrong with globs when used with `nullglob` flag?

Regarding `find` - it's similar to using `ls` in for loops  (which is a common anti-pattern, see the link above). I believe using `find` is an anti-pattern, too. It may fail for many reasons (i.e. outputting errors instead of file names), it may output errors in the middle of file list when it iterates over inaccessible paths etc.